# How to uncheck a CheckBox when a RadioButton is selected

Tags: .net, xml, checkbox, wix, installation

I am dealing with a WiX installer.

I have this `CheckBox` control:

```
<Control Type="CheckBox" Id="OfficePluginsEnabledCheckbox" Width="107" Height="17" X="11" Y="114" Text="Enable Installed Add-ins" Property="OFFICEPLUGINSENABLED" CheckBoxValue="1"/>
```

I have this `RadioButtonGroup` control:

```
<Control Type="RadioButtonGroup" Property="INSTALLADDINKEYS" Id="AddinKeysRadioButtonGroup" Width="74" Height="45" X="218" Y="131">
    <RadioButtonGroup Property="INSTALLADDINKEYS">
      <RadioButton Text="All Users" Height="17" Value="AllUsers" Width="200" X="0" Y="0" />
      <RadioButton Text="Current User" Height="17" Value="CurrentUser" Width="200" X="0" Y="15" />
      <RadioButton Text="None" Height="17" Value="None" Width="200" X="0" Y="30" />
    </RadioButtonGroup>
    <Publish Property="OFFICEPLUGINSENABLED"><![CDATA[INSTALLADDINKEYS="None"]]></Publish>
</Control>
```

I am trying to de-select `OfficePluginsEnabledCheckbox` when `None` is ticked in the `RadioButtonGroup`. As shown above, I've tried publishing the `OFFICEPLUGINSENABLED` property. However this does not work as `OFFICEPLUGINSENABLED` is never actually published when `None` is ticked. Why is this, and how can I achieve my desired functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a value attribute in your script above. Try the following:

```
<Publish Property="OFFICEPLUGINSENABLED" Value="0"><![CDATA[INSTALLADDINKEYS="None"]]></Publish>
```